# Convert .pem and .pub to .pfx file

Tags: openssl, rsa, pem, pfx

I have a .pem file and a .pub file, I used following commands to create them

```
openssl genrsa -out temp.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in temp.pem -pubout -out temp.pub
```

Now I want to make them to a one .pfx file which is binary and contains both private and public key. Is it possible? how? (I have tested som openssl commands but the file was empty).

I used this command

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in temp.pem -inkey temp.pub -out temp.pfx -name "Temp Certificate"
```

it generates this error:

unable to load private key
17880:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_li
b.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the error because, for the `-inkey` argument, you have to specify a private key; not a public key.

OpenSSL's pkcs12 command doesn't provide a way to consolidate public and private keys into a single file. It is specifically used to consolidate certificates and private keys into a single file. In the above case, what you have is a public key, not a certificate.

From the man page:

`-in filename`
`The filename to read certificates and private keys from, standard input by default. They must all be in PEM format. The order doesn't matter but one private key and its corresponding certificate should be present. If additional certificates are present they will also be included in the PKCS#12 file.`

Note that it specifically mentions that one private key and its corresponding certificate **should** be present. The command that I typically use to generate a PKCS#12 file is:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey private.key -out file.pfx -name "My Certificate"`

Comment: ok, Thank you very much, If I have a .pub and a .pem file how can I generate a .cer file from them. in your openssl command you have used .key file not .pub file

Comment: The private.key is just a private key in the PEM format. The public key is in cert.pem signed by a CA. The question is: what exactly do you want? If you want to generate a certificate/private key pair, then there are OpenSSL commands to do that. Take a look at it here: bit.ly/1h9sA7L. You can also generate certificates from existing private keys: bit.ly/3v9aN5. But, all of this requires a CA (at least self-signed CA) to sign the request. If on the other hand, you just want to package your public and private key into PKCS#12, I don't think there is an OpenSSL command for that. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to stablish a OAuth communication between my oauth conusmer and Jira. On Jira server you have to have a public key which is generate using this command: "openssl rsa -in temp.pem -pubout -out temp.pub". I have tested other formats, it accepts only that one. Now on my consumer I have to have a pfx file which contains the private key corresponding to that public key.

Comment: I changed the place of pem and pub files, still generating error says unable to load private key, ..... bad base64 decode

Comment: Why is the answer? Does not describe how to get the job done, i'm trying to do the same thing us user217648. RSA on jira side, pfx on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this and noticed the above accepted answer does not really offer a solution.

Basically you need to generate a [self signed] certificate from the private key, using commands like this:

```
openssl req \
   -key domain.key \
   -new \
   -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt
```

You can use openssl commands to convert your private key PEM to a .KEY file.

From there you can use openssl commands to convert your key and cert to pfx:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.pfx -inkey domain.key -in domain.crt
```